# CAS server authentication using LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap, authorization, single-sign-on, cas

I have 2 web application and I want to use CAS server connecting to LDAP for authentication. I  have installed apache DS and configured CAS server like this:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/CAS+on+Windows+Quick+Setup+Guide
first I added this to pom.xml in cas server :
    
    ${project.groupId}
    cas-server-support-ldap
    ${project.version}
    
then in deployerConfigContext.xml added this lines:
    
    
    
    
    ldap://localhost:10389

removed the demo authentication handler
added this:
    
    
    
    
for the last steps I have added these 2 steps to libs:
spring-ldap-X.Y.Z.RELEASE-all.jar
cas-server-support-ldap-$VERSION.jar
as soon as I deployed cas server in tomcat, I tried to login using admin/secret credentials but this message appears: 
The credentials you provided cannot be determined to be authentic.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the write up on building a CAS server I did awhile back. It should make it easy to understand.

http://blog.mosheldon.com/2011/04/cas-sso-347-with-ldapad-attributes.html